# Solving Higher Order Polynomial Inequalities in Two Variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Could someone please point me to a solver (software) and also some techniques to solve equations of the kind shown below?

$$
x^{3}y+ay^{3}+by^{2}+cy+dx+exy+fxy^{2}\geq0
$$

Here, $x,y$ are the variables. $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are real numbers.